# Low Quality Posts review task can be completed as "Edit" without actually editing the post

Tags: bug, review, edits, low-quality-posts

When reviewing Low Quality Posts, if you click <kbd>Edit</kbd>, and then click <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> without making any changes to the post, the review task will be completed, and your review will be marked as "Edit". Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11405281
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11430164

I think the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button should be disabled until you make some changes to the post. Alternatively, clicking it without making any changes should have the same result as clicking <kbd>Looks OK</kbd>.

Comment: This is a particularly big problem because, as shown in the second example review, editing removes the post from the review queue.